# Cmake generate executable program

Tags: c++, c++11, cygwin

In my IDE (CLion) I can normally run my program, but when I want to start program directly in folder I see error "not found cygwin1.dll".
I know that I can add folder with cygwin to "PATH" but I don't want to do it
I want to make the program run everywhere, not only my PC.
Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the necessary dlls, aka cygwin1.dll, to the folder where your executeable (.exe) resides. The Windows loader will search there first.

That's because the dlls are part of your program and you have to distribute them with it. This is called *shared linking*. If you want to avoid to this, you can either try to link *statically*, which is very uncommon in a windows setting, or try to get rid of the cygwin reference.

For other mechanisms of dll distribution [look here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#search_order_for_desktop_applications).